# Powershell output to csv file horizontally?

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a simple script to get all apps installed on PC.

```
$app32 = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
$app64 = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
$appAll = $app32 + $app64
$appAll | 
ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} |
Select-Object DisplayName,DisplayVersion |
Sort-Object DisplayName |
Export-Csv c:\work\appversion.csv
```

The result will be vertical, but i need to make a loop to run through a list of PCs then output to a csv file. The ideal result will be like this.

- The selected apps will be listed horizontally in csv file
- All PCs will be listed vertically.

[image]

I did a lot of research for this, but could not find a way to do this.

What i do now is output everything to text file then do `select-string` to pick up matched lines. This way i lost all columns, the entire line will be in one column.

Any idea please? or is there better way to do it?

Comment: So what you have here will query the local registry. Will you run this script and then compile the results in a text file someplace, or will you be re-writing this to access remote registries?

Comment: there could be an enormous number of software items found, it would be simpler to have the PC's names on the horizontal and the software names on the vertical

Comment: @TheMadTechnician This is just a example script for local registry query. I have the script ready for remote registries access. The only thing that i can't do is to have output above.....

Comment: @Jimbo Yeah, it is an idea, I can switch vertical and horizontal later in excel as i wanted. but how to populate results your way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to create a custom object, and then use Add-Member to add each software title to it as a NoteProperty. Collect all those objects (one for each computer) in an array, and output to a CSV. The issue that you are going to have is that you will have lots (I mean L O T S) of software titles, and it only takes the first entry's property list into account when outputting the CSV, so that takes a little extra doing.

You say that you have your script to get things off the remote machines, but don't give us that so I'll work with what you *did* give us. I filtered for MS Updates and Hotfixes, but you can obviously remove or ignore that.

```
$app32 = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
$app64 = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
$appAll = $app32 + $app64
$AllComputers = @()
ForEach($CompName in (GC C:\ListOfComputers.txt)){
    $Computer = [PSCustomObject]@{"PC Name"=$CompName}

    $appAll | 
    ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} |
    ?{!($_.displayname -match "(?:Update|Hotfix) for Microsoft") -and !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.DisplayName))}|
    Select-Object DisplayName,DisplayVersion |
    Sort-Object DisplayName|
    %{
        Add-Member -InputObject $Computer -NotePropertyName $_.DisplayName -NotePropertyValue $_.DisplayVersion
    }

    $AllComputers+=$Computer
}
#Make sure first computer has properties for all possible software titles
$AllComputers|
    %{
        $_|GM -MemberType Properties|select -expand Name
    }|
    Select -Unique|
    ?{$_ -notin ($AllComputers[0]|gm -MemberType Properties|select -Expand Name)}|
    %{
        Add-Member -InputObject $AllComputers[0] -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue ""
    }
#Output to file
$AllComputers|Export-Csv $NewFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

**Edit:** To try and explain it, what that does is makes a PSCustomObject for each computer with 1 property: PC Name. It sets the value for that property to whatever computer it's working on at the moment.

Then it gets all the registry values like you were doing already, and for each one it adds another property to that PSCustomObject that it had created for that computer. The property names are the titles of the software, and the values are the software versions. So after the first PC on your hypothetical up there you would have an object that looked like:

```
PC Name    : PC 1
MS Office  : 2013
Adobe      : 9
7-Zip      : 5.2
VNC        : 7
PowerShell : 4.5
```

Add that object to an array, then rinse and repeat for each computer. By the time you're done you have an array that outputs just like you wanted it to. You pipe that array to Format-Table and you get:

```
PC Name MS Office Adobe 7-Zip VNC PowerShell
------- --------- ----- ----- --- ----------
PC 1    2013      9     5.2     7 4.5       
PC 2    2007      11    5.2     7 4.5       
PC 3    2013      11    5.2     7 2         
PC 4    2013      9     5.2     7 3
```

The catch is that it only shows properties that the first item in the array has. So let's say that PC 1 doesn't have 7-Zip installed. Now your first item in the array looks like this:

```
PC Name    : PC 1
MS Office  : 2013
Adobe      : 9
VNC        : 7
PowerShell : 4.5
```

And since it doesn't have the 7-Zip property when you pipe the array to Format-Table you end up getting:

```
PC Name MS Office Adobe VNC PowerShell
------- --------- ----- --- ----------
PC 1    2013      9       7 4.5       
PC 2    2007      11      7 4.5       
PC 3    2013      11      7 2         
PC 4    2013      9       7 3
```

Now that's just no good because we want to see the version numbers for all titles on all machines, so that first record needs to have a property for each software title on any machine, regardless of if it is installed or not on the first computer. To accomplish that we loop through the array by piping it to a ForEach (I use the % alias) loop:

```
$AllComputers|
    %{
```

In that ForEach loop we take the current computer and perform Get-Member (GM alias used), and select only the members that are properties (excluding Methods, or Events that may be on the object), and expand the Name of each property.

```
        $_|GM -MemberType Properties|select -expand Name
```

Now remember our property names were the software titles and values were the versions for each title, but we just want the name so this gives us a list of each software title on every computer. So from there we pipe to Select -Unique to get rid of duplicates, and continue to pipe into a Where clause (alias ? used) to filter out any properties that already exist for that first computer:

```
    Select -Unique|
    ?{$_ -notin ($AllComputers[0]|gm -MemberType Properties|select -Expand Name)}|
```

This is done by getting the names of the properties of the first computer (that's everything in the () in the second line there), and testing to see if each property in the big list of all properties in all computers is already in the list of properties for that one computer. It skips those ones already on it, and for each new one it enters another ForEach loop and does Add-Member to add each property to that first computer, and just uses a value of "" since that computer didn't have it installed.

So now that first entry has properties for all possible software titles, and when we pipe the array to FT (short for Format-Table) we get:

```
PC Name MS Office Adobe VNC PowerShell 7-Zip
------- --------- ----- --- ---------- -----
PC 1    2013      9       7 4.5             
PC 2    2007      11      7 4.5        5.2  
PC 3    2013      11      7 2          5.2  
PC 4    2013      9       7 3          5.2
```

Comment: Thanks for help. This will take me while to fully understand your concepts.   gonna try it first. I m not gonna get all software list, will only pickup some sotware needed.

Comment: I added some more detailed explanation to the answer to help you understand what I did.